# PostConstruct no longer available

Tags: java, rcp, e4, java-11

i used the current versions of Eclipse and Java.
I try to moved my RCP application from Java 8 to Java 11. My applications runs but now i have functional issues because i have to remove the **@PostConstruct** annotation from my code.

Exist any other alternative for this injection annotation?

Comment: i find a way to replace it with for example for "init" method but what can do for method with patameters (e.g. public void createControls(Composite parent))?

I use this way to replace the methods without parameter:
https://better-coding.com/spring-postconstruct-and-predestroy-alternatives-in-java-9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Eclipse e4 the `PostConstruct` annotation is in the `javax.annotation` plug-in. Add that as a dependency to your plug-ins and continue to use PostConstruct.